# If statement does not return right

Tags: php

I have a if statement that's not going well. I have to check if $video and & adopted both are 1. I declared them before of course. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php if($video_id & $adopted_id == '1'): ?>
<?php echo "test"; ?>  
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need multiple PHP tags:

```
<?php
if($video_id == '1' && $adopted_id == '1'):
    echo "test"; 
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
if($video_id == '1' && $adopted_id == '1'):
```

or:

```
if($video_id == '1' && $adopted_id == $video_id):
```

The `&` operator is not the AND operator you are thinking of. Use `&&` instead. Also, each of the variable must be tested for its own value. You can't just translate:

> video and adopter should be equal to 1

directly to code.

Comment: As there aren't any other operators, this is also a case where you could use the keyword `and` instead of `&&`, which can prevent mix-ups between bitwise and logical entirely.

Answer (score 1):

Use logical [`and`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) (&&). you are using bitwise [`AND`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)(&)

```
<?php if($video_id && $adopted_id == '1'): ?>
```

The above condition checks if $video_id has a value and $adopted_id equals to 1.

To check if both values are `1`, you need

```
<?php if($video_id == '1' && $adopted_id == '1'): ?>
```

As your checking numeric value, you do not need to check with string `1`.

```
<?php if($video_id == 1 && $adopted_id == 1): ?>
```

Comment: `if($video_id && $adopted_id == '1')` means if `$video_id` is set and `$adopted_id` is equal to 1, so `$video_id = 2` will be passed to the if statement too.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do like this

```
 <?php if($video_id & $adopted_id == '1'): ?>   //  if(true && true?/false?)
```

change to:

```
<?php if($video_id == '1' && $adopted_id == '1'): ?>  // if(true?/false? AND true?/false?)   //logical AND is &&
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Need to use `&&`

```
<?php if($video_id==1 && $adopted_id == 1): ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php if($video_id & $adopted_id == '1'): ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One & is the bitwise and operation, it looks at the two expressions on each side, breaks them down to the bit level and does an and operation on each bit. This isn't something very many programmers use or need very often.

Instead, use the && operator. That is the more traditional logical and. The same goes for other operator. Use || for or, not |, == for comparison not = (which is assignment).

For a list of all php operators, look here: [php operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php)

In addition, although it makes sense to us to say "a and b are equal to 1", the compiler will not understand "a && b == 1". This will check if 'a' is true by itself, and then if b == 1. 'a' being true by itself sound odd, but imagine that a was either the value true or false and it'll make more sense. Instead you need to write (a == 1 && b == 1). If you are checking whether $video_id is 1 because it might otherwise be 0, and you don't have to worry about other numbers like 4 or 17 or whatever, you can actually write the following:

```
if ($video_id && $adopted_id):
```

This might look odd, but what you are checking when you don't have any == sign is that they are not '0'. This statement will be false if either variable is 0.